# Is there any way I can access Django template variables and URL tags in a JS file so that the user can not inspect the data and links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I want to access Django template variables and URL tags from my javascript file. currently, I'm doing it like follows-

```
    <script>
        const addcommentlink = "{% url 'post:add_comment'%}";
        const postid = '{{post.id}}';
        const deletecommentlink = "{% url 'post:delete_comment' %}";
        const editlikelink = "{% url 'post:edit_like' %}";
        const profilelink = "{% url 'instagram:profile' 'name' %}";
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'post/js/post_details.js' %}"></script>
```

but I want to access it directly from the `post_details.js` file. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#the-django-template-language) in javascript files.

You can use variables, tags, filters only in a django template.

> A template is a text file. It can generate any text-based format (HTML, XML, CSV, etc.).

If you want to access the result of `{% url 'name' %}` in a javascript file, you must first render it in the template(maybe store it as a *data attribute*).

A rough example:

```html
<div id="comment" data-add-link="{% url 'post:add_comment'%}" data-delete-link="{% url 'post:delete_comment' %}"></div>
```

in your `post_details.js`:

```js
const addcommentlink = $('#comment').data('add-link');
const deletecommentlink = $('#comment').data('delete-link');
```

However the user will be able to inspect the data links. And if you need anything in the template, then you must assume that it will be visible to the other users.